# Menu Dropdown do Bootstrap em site asp.net funciona apenas na página principal, o que fazer para corrigi-lo?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

O menu `dropdown` aparentemente funciona na página principal, mas quando estou em outra página e vou utilizá-lo ele não funciona! Já verifiquei se no código HTML está gerando com o jQuery e não vi nada de estranho. O que fazer?

```
<body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="navbar-header">

               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">sis</a>
           </div>
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cadastros<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                            <li><a href="PessoasFisica/frmConPessoaFisica.aspx">Consulta de Pessoa Fisica</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
    </nav>   
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script> $(document).ready(function () { $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(); }); </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Tem alguns erros no seu código, falta fechar algumas tags, e está faltando o `bootstrap.min.css`. E não precisa colocar o `bootstrap.js` e o `bootstrap.min.js` (só o `.min.js` já basta, a mesma coisa com o jQuery). Este menu é pra ser de três níveis? Tipo menu>cadastro>consulta de pessoa fisica (3 níveis) ou o menu aparece ao lado mesmo, e o consulta de pessoa física está dentro de Cadastro (2 níveis)? Dá uma olhada se é mais ou menos isso que vc precisa:  http://jsfiddle.net/chirayu45/yxkut/16/

Comment: Não tem um nível mesmo. Quanto ao bootstrap.min.css ele está no header da Masterpage. O problema é que quando eu estou por exemplo no form de Consulta, o DropdownMenu não funciona. A URL fica assim:
http://localhost:1078/PessoasFisica/frmConPessoaFisica.aspx#

Comment: Acho que a resposta do @dHEKU vai solucionar. Veja o exemplo que ele postou no Bootply, e se isso resolver seu problema, não esqueça de aceitar a resposta dele (é assim que agradecemos por aqui ;)).

Comment: O meu bootstrap funcionando apenas na primeira página, então não adianta eu colocar o meu código no http://www.bootply.com/Y60uWy24UY, pois ele só irá mostrar o bootstrap funcionando normalmente. O meu problema está na URL do ASP.NET que não está alterando quando estou em outra página.

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa colocar o `jquery` de ativação do `dropdown` a não ser que queira utilizar algum evento em conjunto com o clique ou qualquer outra coisa - Só com formatação você consegue colocar ele para funcionar. Retire também os `js` externos não necessários:

http://www.bootply.com/Y60uWy24UY

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">sis</a>
           </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Cadastro <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="PessoasFisica/frmConPessoaFisica.aspx">Consulta de Pessoa Fisica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
    </nav> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: O meu bootstrap funcionando apenas na primeira página, então não adianta eu colocar o meu código no http://www.bootply.com/Y60uWy24UY, pois ele só irá mostrar o bootstrap funcionando normalmente. O meu problema está na URL do ASP.NET que não está alterando quando estou em outra página.

Comment: Então é um problema na estrutura do seu MVC, verifique se o plugin jquery do bootstrap esta sendo carregado em todas as páginas.

Comment: O meu projeto é WebForms, talvez faça a diferença. Já utilizei em MVC e funcionou perfeitamente.